# When filing a US 1065 as a General Partnership, do we combine our expenditures for a home office?

Tags: united-states, taxes, general-partnership

I am in a General Partnership with 1 other person.

We both work out of our respective homes.
When filing expenses on a 1065, do we line item each of our home office expenses?
For example, if I use my internet 50% of the time for work, and he does too, do we line item internet usage at 50% twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your home doesn't belong to the partnership, it belongs to you. So **you** can (if qualified) deduct home office usage as a business expense on **your** individual tax return. Same goes to your partner.

Similarly any other unreimbursed expense.